# convert rows into corresponding columns which are belongs to diffrent categories based on their header's category

Tags: linux, unix, awk, sed, rows

I have input file like this in which **KO** ids like `K00001` ,`K00002`
`K00006` etc. under a specific category like `01100metabolicpathway` , `01523Antifolateresistance(7)`, `01522Endocrineresistance(7)`

```
01100Metabolicpathways(812)
K00001
Ca_19344,Ca_19730
K00002
Ca_09433,Ca_23715,Ca_15858,Ca_19929,Ca_26670
K00008
Ca_20904
K00011
Ca_15431
K00012
Ca_10466,Ca_23867,Ca_06574
K00013
Ca_08009
K00016
Ca_02357,Ca_16304
K00020
Ca_08005
K00021
Ca_10251,Ca_09868
01523Antifolateresistance(7)
K00297
Ca_26773
K00600
Ca_00054,Ca_00455,Ca_14951,Ca_11397,Ca_08538,Ca_11540,Ca_11173
01522Endocrineresistance(7)
K04650
Ca_20380,Ca_04277
```

desired output like this:

```
K00001  Ca_19344,Ca_19730   01100Metabolicpathways(812)
K00002  Ca_09433,Ca_23715,Ca_15858,Ca_19929,Ca_26670    01100Metabolicpathways(812)
K00006  Ca_14695,Ca_21671,Ca_07219,Ca_24024,Ca_23566,Ca_27084   01100Metabolicpathways(812)
K00008  Ca_20904    01100Metabolicpathways(812)
K00011  Ca_15431    01100Metabolicpathways(812)
K00012  Ca_10466,Ca_23867,Ca_06574  01100Metabolicpathways(812)
K00013  Ca_08009    01100Metabolicpathways(812)
K00016  Ca_02357,Ca_16304   01100Metabolicpathways(812)
K00020  Ca_08005    01100Metabolicpathways(812)
K00021  Ca_10251,Ca_09868   01100Metabolicpathways(812)
K00297  Ca_26773    01523Antifolateresistance(7)
K00600  Ca_00054,Ca_00455,Ca_14951,Ca_11397,Ca_08538,Ca_11540,Ca_11173  01523Antifolateresistance(7)    
K04650  Ca_20380,Ca_04277   01522Endocrineresistance(7)
```

I have wrote something like this  by taking out **KO** ids into `KO_list.txt` file,

```
K00001
K00002
K00006
K00008
K00011
K00012
K00013
K00016
K00020
K00021
for n in `cat KO_list.txt`
do
x=$(cat $2 | grep  -w -A1 "^$n"  | head -2 | sed ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n/\t/g')
echo -e "$x" | awk 'NF' >> output.txt
done
```

but it gives me output like this only

```
K00001  Ca_19344,Ca_19730   
K00002  Ca_09433,Ca_23715,Ca_15858,Ca_19929,Ca_26670    
K00006  Ca_14695,Ca_21671,Ca_07219,Ca_24024,Ca_23566,Ca_27084   
K00008  Ca_20904    
K00011  Ca_15431    
K00012  Ca_10466,Ca_23867,Ca_06574  
K00013  Ca_08009    
K00016  Ca_02357,Ca_16304   
K00020  Ca_08005
K00021  Ca_10251,Ca_09868   
K00297  Ca_26773    
K00600  Ca_00054,Ca_00455,Ca_14951,Ca_11397,Ca_08538,Ca_11540,Ca_11173  
K04650  Ca_20380,Ca_04277
```

any help guys

######### SECOND PART

thanks everyone , i realy appreciate all of yours valubale comments, it also has second part is there any way to have ouput based on Ca-ids in which Ca-ids are in first column and have information for each Ca-ids seprately instead of KO-ids either directly  from  input file or from desired output file in which KO-ids are in first column, i am looking for output like this from any of the same file.

either from this input file

```
01100Metabolicpathways(812)
K00001
Ca_19344,Ca_19730
01522Endocrineresistance(7)
K04650
Ca_20380,Ca_04277
```

or from this output file created from input file

```
K00001  Ca_19344,Ca_19730   01100Metabolicpathways(812)
K04650  Ca_20380,Ca_04277   01522Endocrineresistance(7)
```

new desired ouput should be like this

```
Ca_19344    K00001  01100Metabolicpathways(812)
Ca_19730    K00001  01100Metabolicpathways(812)
Ca_20380    K04650  01522Endocrineresistance(7)
Ca_04277    K04650  01522Endocrineresistance(7)
```

thanks in advance

Comment: why was category missed for the line `K00020  Ca_08005` in your desired output?

Comment: hii @RomanPerekhrest , K00020  has a category 01100Metabolicpathways(812) as shown in the input file but it is missed in the desired output file as I make it manually. now I have done the correction.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a cheap solution but it works for your Input:

```
awk '/^[0-9].*/{ h = $0; next }/^K/{ k = $0; next }{ print k, $0, h }' yourfile
```

Output:

```
K00001 Ca_19344,Ca_19730 01100Metabolicpathways(812)
K00002 Ca_09433,Ca_23715,Ca_15858,Ca_19929,Ca_26670 01100Metabolicpathways(812)
K00008 Ca_20904 01100Metabolicpathways(812)
K00011 Ca_15431 01100Metabolicpathways(812)
K00012 Ca_10466,Ca_23867,Ca_06574 01100Metabolicpathways(812)
K00013 Ca_08009 01100Metabolicpathways(812)
K00016 Ca_02357,Ca_16304 01100Metabolicpathways(812)
K00020 Ca_08005 01100Metabolicpathways(812)
K00021 Ca_10251,Ca_09868 01100Metabolicpathways(812)
K00297 Ca_26773 01523Antifolateresistance(7)
K00600 Ca_00054,Ca_00455,Ca_14951,Ca_11397,Ca_08538,Ca_11540,Ca_11173 01523Antifolateresistance(7)
```

So, what this one liner basically does is capturing certain lines into variables. So the first part `/^[0-9].*/{ h = $0; next }` captures a line that starts with a number like your category identifiers. Awk sees the line 01100metabolicpathway and stores it into the variable h. Then the `next` command is executed and and awk reads the next line. The second part `/^K/{ k = $0; next }` executes when a line starts with a K. Like your KO id's. Again awk is storing the whole line into a variable and proceeding to the next one. Now the las part `{ print k, $0, h }` is executed when a line is not meeting any of the mentioned criteria ( starting with a K or a number ). Then the content of variable k, the whole current line and the content of variable h. That leads to the desired output.

Comment: thanks @JFS31 , it works fine can you explain it little bit ,  thanks again.

Comment: Explaination is on it's way. I was out for lunch ;)

Comment: Thank you so much @JFS31 , it really good can you just help me out in second of question I just updated.

Comment: Hey there, if my answer to your first question helped you it would be nice if you accept it as an answer. For the second question you should post it as a new one so that everyone gets the chance to answer it.

Answer (score 0):

```
awk -v OFS=, '/^K/{k=$0;next}/^C/{ print k, $0 " " c; k=""; next}{c=$0}' infile
```

Explanation

```
awk -v OFS=, '                            # set output field separator
              /^K/{                       # if line starts with K
                    k=$0;                 # variable k = current line/record
                    next                  # go to next line
              } 
             /^C/{                        # if line starts with C 
                    print k, $0 " " c;    # print variable k, current row and variable c
                    k="";                 # nullify variable k
                    next                  # go to next line
              }
              {
                    c=$0                  # if from above statement line not
                                          # skipped then variable c will be category
              }
            ' infile
```

Input

```
$ cat infile
01100Metabolicpathways(812)
K00001
Ca_19344,Ca_19730
K00002
Ca_09433,Ca_23715,Ca_15858,Ca_19929,Ca_26670
K00008
Ca_20904
K00011
Ca_15431
K00012
Ca_10466,Ca_23867,Ca_06574
K00013
Ca_08009
K00016
Ca_02357,Ca_16304
K00020
Ca_08005
K00021
Ca_10251,Ca_09868
01523Antifolateresistance(7)
K00297
Ca_26773
K00600
Ca_00054,Ca_00455,Ca_14951,Ca_11397,Ca_08538,Ca_11540,Ca_11173
01522Endocrineresistance(7)
K04650
Ca_20380,Ca_04277
```

Output

```
$ awk -v OFS=, '/^K/{k=$0;next}/^C/{ print k,$0" "c ; k=""; next}{c=$0}' infile
K00001,Ca_19344,Ca_19730 01100Metabolicpathways(812)
K00002,Ca_09433,Ca_23715,Ca_15858,Ca_19929,Ca_26670 01100Metabolicpathways(812)
K00008,Ca_20904 01100Metabolicpathways(812)
K00011,Ca_15431 01100Metabolicpathways(812)
K00012,Ca_10466,Ca_23867,Ca_06574 01100Metabolicpathways(812)
K00013,Ca_08009 01100Metabolicpathways(812)
K00016,Ca_02357,Ca_16304 01100Metabolicpathways(812)
K00020,Ca_08005 01100Metabolicpathways(812)
K00021,Ca_10251,Ca_09868 01100Metabolicpathways(812)
K00297,Ca_26773 01523Antifolateresistance(7)
K00600,Ca_00054,Ca_00455,Ca_14951,Ca_11397,Ca_08538,Ca_11540,Ca_11173 01523Antifolateresistance(7)
K04650,Ca_20380,Ca_04277 01522Endocrineresistance(7)
```

--edit--

```
For new input

$ cat infile_new
K00001  Ca_19344,Ca_19730   01100Metabolicpathways(812)
K04650  Ca_20380,Ca_04277   01522Endocrineresistance(7)

$ awk  '{split($2,a,/,/); for(i=1; i in a; i++)print a[i], $1,  $3}' infile_new
Ca_19344 K00001 01100Metabolicpathways(812)
Ca_19730 K00001 01100Metabolicpathways(812)
Ca_20380 K04650 01522Endocrineresistance(7)
Ca_04277 K04650 01522Endocrineresistance(7)
```

Comment: can  you help me in the second part of this, I updated my question.

Comment: @a.k use this for new input file `awk  '{split($2,a,/,/); for(i=1; i in a; i++)print a[i], $1,  $3}' infile`

Comment: Thanks again buddy you rock again, just hoping for little bit explanation.

Comment: @a.k split second column using separator comma and store elements in array a, then loop through array a print array element, column1 and column3

Answer (score 0):

Short **awk** solution:

```
awk '/^[0-9]/{ cat=$0;next }cat{ printf "%s %s",$0,(/^Ca/)? cat"\n":"" }' file
```

The output:

```
K00001 Ca_19344,Ca_19730 01100Metabolicpathways(812)
K00002 Ca_09433,Ca_23715,Ca_15858,Ca_19929,Ca_26670 01100Metabolicpathways(812)
K00008 Ca_20904 01100Metabolicpathways(812)
K00011 Ca_15431 01100Metabolicpathways(812)
K00012 Ca_10466,Ca_23867,Ca_06574 01100Metabolicpathways(812)
K00013 Ca_08009 01100Metabolicpathways(812)
K00016 Ca_02357,Ca_16304 01100Metabolicpathways(812)
K00020 Ca_08005 01100Metabolicpathways(812)
K00021 Ca_10251,Ca_09868 01100Metabolicpathways(812)
K00297 Ca_26773 01523Antifolateresistance(7)
K00600 Ca_00054,Ca_00455,Ca_14951,Ca_11397,Ca_08538,Ca_11540,Ca_11173 01523Antifolateresistance(7)
K04650 Ca_20380,Ca_04277 01522Endocrineresistance(7)
```

---

***Bonus*** solution for your new condition(second part):

```
awk '/^[0-9]/{ cat=$0;next }cat{ if(/^K/){ k=$0;next } 
     if(/^Ca/){ split($0,a,","); for(i in a) print a[i],k,cat } }' file
```

The output:

```
Ca_19344 K00001 01100Metabolicpathways(812)
Ca_19730 K00001 01100Metabolicpathways(812)
Ca_09433 K00002 01100Metabolicpathways(812)
Ca_23715 K00002 01100Metabolicpathways(812)
Ca_15858 K00002 01100Metabolicpathways(812)
Ca_19929 K00002 01100Metabolicpathways(812)
Ca_26670 K00002 01100Metabolicpathways(812)
Ca_20904 K00008 01100Metabolicpathways(812)
Ca_15431 K00011 01100Metabolicpathways(812)
Ca_10466 K00012 01100Metabolicpathways(812)
Ca_23867 K00012 01100Metabolicpathways(812)
Ca_06574 K00012 01100Metabolicpathways(812)
Ca_08009 K00013 01100Metabolicpathways(812)
Ca_02357 K00016 01100Metabolicpathways(812)
Ca_16304 K00016 01100Metabolicpathways(812)
Ca_08005 K00020 01100Metabolicpathways(812)
Ca_10251 K00021 01100Metabolicpathways(812)
Ca_09868 K00021 01100Metabolicpathways(812)
Ca_26773 K00297 01523Antifolateresistance(7)
Ca_00054 K00600 01523Antifolateresistance(7)
Ca_00455 K00600 01523Antifolateresistance(7)
Ca_14951 K00600 01523Antifolateresistance(7)
Ca_11397 K00600 01523Antifolateresistance(7)
Ca_08538 K00600 01523Antifolateresistance(7)
Ca_11540 K00600 01523Antifolateresistance(7)
Ca_11173 K00600 01523Antifolateresistance(7)
Ca_20380 K04650 01522Endocrineresistance(7)
Ca_04277 K04650 01522Endocrineresistance(7)
```

Comment: Thank you so much @RomanPerekhest, can you help me in the second part of this.

Comment: @a.k, see my bonus aproach

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN { OFS="\t" }
/\(/ { cat=$0; cnt=0; next }
++cnt % 2 { kid=$0; next }
{ print kid, $0, cat }

$ awk -f tst.awk file
K00001  Ca_19344,Ca_19730       01100Metabolicpathways(812)
K00002  Ca_09433,Ca_23715,Ca_15858,Ca_19929,Ca_26670    01100Metabolicpathways(812)
K00008  Ca_20904        01100Metabolicpathways(812)
K00011  Ca_15431        01100Metabolicpathways(812)
K00012  Ca_10466,Ca_23867,Ca_06574      01100Metabolicpathways(812)
K00013  Ca_08009        01100Metabolicpathways(812)
K00016  Ca_02357,Ca_16304       01100Metabolicpathways(812)
K00020  Ca_08005        01100Metabolicpathways(812)
K00021  Ca_10251,Ca_09868       01100Metabolicpathways(812)
K00297  Ca_26773        01523Antifolateresistance(7)
K00600  Ca_00054,Ca_00455,Ca_14951,Ca_11397,Ca_08538,Ca_11540,Ca_11173  01523Antifolateresistance(7)
K04650  Ca_20380,Ca_04277       01522Endocrineresistance(7)
```

Comment: Thanks you so much @Ed Morton for the valuable answer, can you assist me in the second part of this.

Comment: [Chameleon questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/43478/361691) are frowned upon on this site. Accept an answer to your original question and then ask a new, followup question that stands alone.